# Prove that there eixst solution of $x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have equation: $$x'(t)=f(t,x(t))$$Our assumptions are $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}, (t,x)\mapsto f(t,x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ are both continuous. Morover there exist continuous $k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $|\frac{df}{dx}(t,x)|\leq k(t)$.

Prove that there exists solution of the above equation such as $x(t_0)=x_0$ for $t\in[t_0,\infty]$

I even don't know how to start it.

Comment: Have a look at Picard-Lindelof theorem and its proof, e.g.: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard–Lindelöf_theorem)

Comment: Look at the [simplified conditions for existence and uniqeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Local_existence_and_uniqueness_theorem_simplified)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove $f$ is locally Lipschitz continuous in $x$ (Weirstrass' theorem) and apply Picard-Lindelöf

Comment: Is following reasoning roughly correct? Ok, so let's use Picard-Lindelöf arount $t_0$. We know that there is such $\epsilon$ that this solutions is unique on $[t_0,t_0+\epsilon)$. If $\epsilon<\infty$ then we can take maximum $\epsilon_m$ possible such that given solution is unique. But than applying Picard-Lindelöf again (because assumptions are satisfied) to $t_0+\epsilon_m$ guarantee that there exist unique solution on $(t_0+\epsilon_m-\delta,t_0+\epsilon_m-\delta)$ which contradicts that $\epsilon_m$ was maximal therefore we have solution on $[t_0,\infty]$